# Cannot format the ticklabel in the twin x axis in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, formatting

I would like to plot a figure with double x axis, and format the ticklabel in the upper axis to scientific notations.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imp1=np.arange(0,2,2/50)
imp1_pdf=np.arange(0,6,6/50)

fig1=plt.figure()
axs1=fig1.add_subplot(111)
axs1.set_xlim(0,2)
axs1.set_ylim(0,6.5)

axs2 = axs1.twiny()

axs1.plot(imp1,imp1_pdf)

new_tick_locations=axs1.get_xticks()

axs2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
axs2.set_xticklabels(new_tick_locations/1000)
axs2.axes.ticklabel_format(axis='x',style='sci',scilimits=(0,0))

axs1.grid(b=True, which='major',linestyle='-')
fig1.tight_layout()
fig1.savefig('tickformat.png',dpi=600)
```

Without the ticklabel formatting, the figure looks like this:
[image]

But when I try to format the upper x axis, there is an error like this:

> AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter.

If I use an alternative method, which is to use the `FormatStrFormatter`

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

axs2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.1e'))
```

The upper x axis value will become the same with the lower x axis value like this:
[image]

Could someone tell me how to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to modify the custom labels which are just strings you defined `(new_tick_locations/1000)`. The real values on the twin axis **are the same** as that on the lower axis. You are just modifying the tick labels. One way to get things done is to construct modified tick labels in Scientific Format using `Decimal` and then assign them to the upper x-axis. You can then choose any factor instead of 1000, which you want to display

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imp1=np.arange(0,2,2/50)
imp1_pdf=np.arange(0,6,6/50)

fig1=plt.figure()
axs1=fig1.add_subplot(111)
axs1.set_xlim(0,2)
axs1.set_ylim(0,6.5)

axs2 = axs1.twiny()
axs1.plot(imp1,imp1_pdf)

new_tick_locations=axs1.get_xticks()
ticks = ['%.2E' % Decimal(i) for i in (new_tick_locations/1000)] # <-- make new ticks
axs2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
axs2.set_xticklabels(ticks, rotation = 45) # <-- assign new ticks and rotate them

axs1.grid(b=True, which='major',linestyle='-')
fig1.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is great!